# Count number of points on a line in R

Tags: r, point, line, sf, rgeos

I have a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` and a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. I want to calculate the number of points that fall on a line by a specific field in the lines data frame.

Example: I have a river network broken up into 125 fragments with a specific length: I want to count the number of points that fall in each of the 125 fragments. Is there a function to do this like `poly.counts`?
[image]

Comment: "point on a line" is tricky, due to arithmetic rounding. Better to compute the distance from point to nearest line point and use a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `over()` to emulate the `poly.counts` you mentioned. There will still be the issue with the rounding of coordinates @Spacedman mentioned, but looking the image you attached it looks like points could match. Having your data (or your code) could help us to provide more precise assistance; I provide you with some main lines to follow to apply the `over()` function:

```
library(rgdal)
library(data.table)

rivers <- readOGR(...) # load your rivers' data
rivers@data$id <- 1:nrow(rivers) # to make sure there is data associated with your rivers' dataset
rivers@data <- data.table(rivers@data)

points <- readOGR(...) # load your SpatialPointsDataFrame
```

Assuming each of the 125 fragments you mention is a different object of your `SpatialLinesDataFrame`, you can loop over as

```
rivers@data$count <- as.numeric(NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(rivers)) {
    rivers[i,'count'] <- sum(!is.na(over(points, rivers[,'id'])))
}
```

The `over()` function retrieves a vector with the dimension of `points` containing the `'id'` of the `rivers[i,'id']` feature (each fragment) laying under each point of `points`. The points which do not lay over a line would have a `<NA>` associated to it. Thus, `sum(!is.na(...))` provides you with the number of points which have been found to be laying over the fragment. Looping over each fragment, you would have the count for each of them.